# Resharper: Unable to "see" .Net Framework Project

Tags: resharper

I have a .Net Core 3.1 web site that references a .Net 4.8 Framework project. Works great.

However, Resharper complains that all the .Net Framework items referenced in the .Net Core website are bad "Cannot resolve..."

When I turn off Resharper, Visual Studio 2019 see them all fine.

I have cleared Resharper's cache, rebooted etc.

[image: Resharper]

Comment: Try to turn off ReSharper > Options > Environment > General > Read solution model directly from project/solution files and restart ReSharper. Please write if that would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that if I use .NET 4.7.2, then Resharper can see the projects.

```
.Net core 3.x + .Net 4.8 fails

.Net core 3.x + .Net 4.7.2 works
```

I've moved back to 4.7.2 for now.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you faced the issue in ReSharper which has already been reported on [a bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-477432). I hope it will be fixed in the next update.